# Understanding how to use a future in realtion to scaffold api call

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use a future builder from this tutorial here.
https://github.com/CoderJava/Flutter-CRUD-API-Sample/blob/master/lib/src/ui/home/home_screen.dart

But my code is doing the following

Here

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String username;
    String password;
    final usernameController =
        TextEditingController(text: 'brandon@hockeylabmn.com');
    final passwordController = TextEditingController(text: 'Fitness1!@');

    void submitForm() async {
      api.login(usernameController.text, passwordController.text);
      fetchItems();
    }

    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(      
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],      
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              'Welcome:${stations?.playerName}',
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
```

Tutorial Code

```
 child: FutureBuilder(
        future: apiService.getStationData(11),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Stations> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Something wrong with message: ${snapshot.error.toString()}"),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            Stations stationData = snapshot.data;
            return _buildListView(stationData);
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
```

Basically the issue I am having is am loosing the data from my api call where I am setting the welcome text for example

```
'Welcome:${stations?.playerName}',
```

I was told a nedded to use a future but i cant get the placement of the future right in the return scaffold function where should I place the above future statment.

This is my api call which lives in httpservices.dart

```
Future<Stations?> getStationData(int playerId) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String? token = prefs.getString('jwtToken');
    const String path = 'Station/GetFirstPlayerStationTopScore';

    final uri = Uri.parse('$url/api/$path');

    final Map<String, String> queryParams = {
      'playerId': '25801',
      'type': '11',
    };
    final Uri uriWithParams = uri.replace(queryParameters: queryParams);

    try {
      Response res = await get(uriWithParams, headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        // 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      });

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        var body = jsonDecode(res.body);
        print(body);
        if (body != null) {
          return Stations.fromJson(body);
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      } else {
        throw Exception('Unable to retrieve posts.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      throw Exception('Unable to retrieve posts.');
    }
  }
```